# Customizing UITabbar idea ?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I read many posts on customizing color of selected tabbar item which is actually blue by default.

My idea was to put an UIImageView on each of my button.
Once the user select one button, I would then display the image (which is the same icon but with another colour as a gradient).

What do you think about that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use this http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/04/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar/ and change it to include text and modify the colour.

Comment: I will have a look at that. Thanks :). I just wanted to avoid that tricky part of creating it from scratch :P

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, iOS 5 introduced an appearance proxy allowing customisation of most basic UI elements, including the trusty UITabBar. The proxy is used to change ALL instances of a class throughout an application. However, with this came some basic properties available for specific instances.

See the selectedImageTintColor property of UITabBar for your needs.

Other appearance additions for this class are tintColor, backgroundImage and selectionIndicatorImage.